# Android device name == "BlueZ"?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez

I am new to Android development and built 4.0.3 from source. build.prop does list my device as "Incredible 2" yet in the Bluetooth settings my device is listed as "BlueZ". Sure I can change it but I'd like to know where in the source that is handled so I can see how to fix it.

Comment: BlueZ is the name of the Bluetooth Stack used in Linux and therefore also used in Android. I would check the folders in  /etc/bluetooth, namely the 'main.conf'

Answer (score 1):

BlueZ is the official Linux bluetooth protocol. It's probably just defaulting to the protocol name rather than the device name. I don't have the source on this machine, but I **believe** that in the bluetooth source directory there's a config file that lists the name.

Comment: So I am guessing the Android BT stack cannot get the device type (Incredible 2) so it uses BlueZ instead. But I don't know where to find this conditional code.